# How to define an arbitrary scalar in apollo gql?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have a type that needs to be like the following

```
type ActivityPayload {
  action: String!
  extra: AnythingAtAll
}
```

Where AnythingAtAll is an arbitrary JSON format. So that's as far as I get because all the tutorials I see expect you to have a type AnythingAtAll with fields defined inside of it. How do I allow {}, or {any properties in json format no matter what the property names and values are}

Answer (score 0):

Use [graphql-scalars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-scalars):

> A library of custom GraphQL scalar types for creating precise type-safe GraphQL schemas.

This library offers also the scalar type [`JSON`](https://www.graphql-scalars.dev/docs/scalars/json):

> The JSON scalar type represents JSON values as specified by ECMA-404.

Then you can do the following:

```
type ActivityPayload {
  action: String!
  extra: JSON
}
```

See also [graphql-type-json](https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json) (`JSON` is based on this one).